# Country name missing magento 2 checkout page billing address section

Tags: magento2

Country name is missing on magento 2 checkout page billing address section
can anyone know the solution of this issue magento version is 2.3.5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check in  browser console. May be error exist and becuase of that this will be happening.

Comment: there is no error on browser console

Answer (score 0):

Please check where the person is entering the address, is everything fine there ?
address.phtml file in customer_module , also please check the database address entity table to find if the country is reached into the database table.

Answer (score 0):

Here **$customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();** is an object of **'Magento\Customer\Model\Address'** class and this class extend from **Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress**

So go to **Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress** has some get function that help you a lot. I add a line that help you to pick country.

```
$this->logger->info($customerAddress->getCountry());
```

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class CustomerAddressSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface //
    ) {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $this->logger->debug("CustomerAddressSaveAfterObserver execute");

        $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer();
        $billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
        // get country code
        $this->logger->info($customerAddress->getCountry());
        // get country name
        $this->logger->info($customerAddress->getCountryModel()->getName());
    }

}
```